# add image to uitableview cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit, uiimage

I have a `tableview`, how can I add image to the left of this cells?

Answer (score 134, accepted):

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
```

UPDATE:
Like Steven Fisher said, this should only work for cells with style UITableViewCellStyleDefault which is the default style. For other styles, you'd need to add a UIImageView to the cell's contentView.

Comment: If your cell is of the wrong `UITableviewCellStyle`, it won't have an `imageView`, so you won't be able to set the image this way. I think only `UITableViewCellStyleDefault` supports images in this way; otherwise, you'll need to add your own image view (see Aman's answer).

Comment: Actually if you're using a custom cell you shouldn't do it the way Aman does - you should add views to cell.contentView, not to cell directly.

Comment: But regarding the cell style, you're right, only default cells support imageView - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/UITableViewCellStyleDefault

Comment: This also seems to work for style UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle.

Comment: What is "default"? Basic? Custom?

Answer (score 21):

Try this code:--

```
UIImageView *imv = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3,2, 20, 25)];
imv.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow2.png"];
[cell addSubview:imv];
[imv release];
```

Comment: put the above code inside the method                                 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
   cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

Comment: Instead of adding directly to cell use [cell.contentView addSubview:imv];

Answer (score 13):

Standard UITableViewCell already contains UIImageView that appears to the left to all your labels if its image is set. You can access it using imageView property:

```
cell.imageView.image = someImage;
```

If for some reason standard behavior does not suit your needs (note that you can customize properties of that standard image view) then you can add your own UIImageView to the cell as Aman suggested in his answer. But in that approach you'll have to manage cell's layout yourself (e.g. make sure that cell labels do not overlap image). And do not add subviews to the cell directly - add them to cell's contentView:

```
// DO NOT!
[cell addSubview:imv]; 
// DO:
[cell.contentView addSubview:imv];
```

Answer (score 8):

For my fellow Swift users, here is the code you will need:

```
let imageName = "un-child-rights.jpg"
let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
cell.imageView!.image = image
```

Answer (score 4):

Swift 4 solution:

```
    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "yourImageName")
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5 solution

```
cell.imageView?.image = UIImage.init(named: "yourImageName")
```

Answer (score 0):

All good answers from others. Here are two ways you can solve this:

1. Directly from the code where you will have to programmatically control the dimensions of the imageview

   ```
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "xyz", for: indexPath)
       ...
       cell.imageView!.image = UIImage(named: "xyz") // if retrieving the image from the assets folder 
       return cell
   }
   ```
2. From the story board, where you can use the attribute inspector & size inspector in the utility pane to adjust positioning, add constraints and specify dimensions

   - In the storyboard, add an imageView object in to the cell's content view with your desired dimensions and add a tag to the view(imageView) in the attribute inspector. Then do the following in your viewController

     ```
     override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "xyz", for: indexPath)
         ...
         let pictureView = cell.viewWithTag(119) as! UIImageView //let's assume the tag is set to 119
         pictureView.image = UIImage(named: "xyz") // if retrieving the image from the assets folder 
         return cell
     }
     ```