# iOS: UITableView Table Data Not Showing Up In to Sub Categories:iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I want To Show Data On The Table And that Perticuler Data Have Sub Data

**For Ex.**

1. **Group A**

   1.1 **List of Names**
2. **Group B**

   2.1 **List of Names**

   2.2 **List of Sports**

**Thx In Advance (^_^)**

Comment: Try use `contentInset` for your cells.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement [MultiLevel UITableView](http://sugartin.info/2011/07/20/447/) very good tutorial, thanks to [Sagar](http://sugartin.info/author/sugar/)

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";   
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text=[[self.arForTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"name"];
    [cell setIndentationLevel:[[[self.arForTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"level"] intValue]]; 
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    NSDictionary *d=[self.arForTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if([d valueForKey:@"Objects"]) {
        NSArray *ar=[d valueForKey:@"Objects"];
        BOOL isAlreadyInserted=NO;
        for(NSDictionary *dInner in ar ){
            NSInteger index=[self.arForTable indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:dInner];
            isAlreadyInserted=(index>0 && index!=NSIntegerMax);
            if(isAlreadyInserted) break; 
        }
        if(isAlreadyInserted) {
            [self miniMizeThisRows:ar];
        } else {        
            NSUInteger count=indexPath.row+1;
            NSMutableArray *arCells=[NSMutableArray array];
            for(NSDictionary *dInner in ar ) {
                [arCells addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:count inSection:0]];
                [self.arForTable insertObject:dInner atIndex:count++];
            }
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:arCells withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
        }
    }
}

-(void)miniMizeThisRows:(NSArray*)ar{
    for(NSDictionary *dInner in ar ) {
        NSUInteger indexToRemove=[self.arForTable indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:dInner];     
        NSArray *arInner=[dInner valueForKey:@"Objects"];
        if(arInner && [arInner count]>0){
            [self miniMizeThisRows:arInner];
        }
        if([self.arForTable indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:dInner]!=NSNotFound) {
            [self.arForTable removeObjectIdenticalTo:dInner];
            [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:
              [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexToRemove inSection:0]]
                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thx i Have same Code but When i use This In to My Project All Table Cells Are In The Stright Line.....Wht Should i do now Please

Comment: @RahulSharma did you try [Example code](http://sugartin.info/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/cellMaxMinDemo-Updated.zip) it works very well i have tested on my side, also spend some time to understand the example and try to following the same in your project, I am sure you will get it working.

Comment: Okay Let Me try More And i'll understand To That More I Can thx Once Again And happy coding

Comment: Hey I Found It Problem The Problem Is I'm using Custom Cell With images That's Why My Level Not Working YOu have Any Idea #RDC @RDC

Comment: Than you should look for custom cell, there are tons of example how to use custom cell  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869610/add-image-to-uitableview-cell and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22348994/how-to-add-images-in-uitableviewcells-programatically-in-ios

Comment: Okay (Thumps Up For you ) +1 @RDC

Comment: @RahulSharma I am glad to hear that I could help you.. learn and share ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108884/discussion-between-rahul-sharma-and-rdc).